# How do I make/develop Hibernate caching?

Tags: hibernate

How do I make/develop Hibernate caching?

Comment: Uhm... I'm having second thoughts about your question (and my answer): (1) Java or .NET (2) you mean... to develop an Hibernate cache on your own or to use an existing one?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Hibernate with Dot net application. The would like to use existing hibernate cache mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ehcache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/). Details [here](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/documentation/hibernate.html). Some alternatives in [this not-so-up-to-date article](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/29685).